# Find identical keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

I was wondering if there is some sort of tool/option in the Dope Sheet that would highlight all the keyframes that has the exact same value in loc/rot/scale or just one of those in a different color or key type.

Because sometimes I duplicate keys and shifting them around in different orders and I end up losing track of which keys do what.

An extreme example would be in this image:
[image]

It would be nice if I could just toggle something and everytime I select a key all the keys with the same value would change color but only one of them would be selected.

Thanks!

Comment: I'mnot sure about how to do it in the Dope sheet but, if you don't have too many objects, the Graph editor is a good choice for displaying more information: not only the keyframes' position, but also their value (of course it gets very crowded for 5+ objects). Once you are visualizing a curve in the Graph editor, you can rectangle-select with "B" all the keyframes having the same y-value.